# Where to store user file uploads?

Tags: clojure, upload, compojure

In my compojure app, where should I store user upload files? Do I just make a `user-upload` dir in my project root and stick everything in there? Is there anything special I should do (classpath, permissions, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly answer your question, you need to think of the lifecycle of the uploaded files. I would start answering questions such as:

- how big are the files going to be?
- what storage options will hold enough data to store all the uploads?
- how about SLAs, redundancy and disaster avoidance?
- how and who to monitor the free space and health of the storage?

In general, the file system location is much less relevant than the block device sitting behind it: as long as your data is stored safely enough for your application, `user-upload` can be anywhere and be anything from a regular disk to an [S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) e.g. via [`s3fs-fuse`](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse).

Putting such folder in your classpath sounds odd to me. It gives no essential benefit, as you will always need to go through a configuration entry to state where to store and read files from.

Permission wise, your application will require at least write access to the upload storage (most likely read access as well). Granting such permissions depends on the physical device you choose: if you opt for the local file system as you suggest in your question, you need to make sure the Clojure app is run by a user with `chmod +rw`, but in case of S3, you will need to configure API keys.

Answer (score 1):

For anything other than a practice problem, I would suggest using a database such as Postgres or Datomic.  This way, you get the reliability of a DB with real transactions, along with the ability to access the files across a network from any location.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/datomic/vsoeiQ-jPLM/Xl72nLiTAi4J Unless things have changed since, it doesn't seem to be a fantastic idea with datomic.